# Get $n$ where $x = 10^n$

Tags: exponentiation

Say we have $x = 10^n$.
Is there a way to simplify/change this equation to isolate $n$, e.g. represent $n$ as a function of $x$?

Just too add a few lines and not get this question posponed, please represet the answer as "$n = \dots$"

Comment: Do you know anything about logarithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the *logarithm*. If $x = 10^n$, then $n = \log_{10}(x)$. You can use this as the definition of the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of exponential is logarithm.
$n=\log_{10}x$